# Query for determining related tags

Tags: mysql, sql

I am hoping for some help with constructing an efficient method for picking out related tags

rough DB:

```
CREATE TABLE blog (
    blog_id INT,
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE tag (
    blog_id INT
    tag VARCHAR(20),
);

CREATE TABLE tag_count (
    tag VARCHAR(20),
    times INT
);
```

Table 'tag' looks like this:

```
1, 'cat'
1, 'cheeseburger'
2, 'dog'
2, 'cheeseburger'
2, 'ham'
```

Table 'tag_count' looks like this:

```
'cat', 1
'cheeseburger', 2
'dog', 1
'ham', 1
```

I am attempting to find the related tags for an entry. So for example, if you're looking at blog #2, the related tag is 'cat' because both blog entries share the tag 'cheeseburger'. If you're looking at blog #1, the related tag is 'dog' and 'ham', because both entries share the tag 'cheeseburger'.

Hence, the method should find related tags based on blog_id AND ignore the shared tag (ie 'cheeseburger'). What is the most efficient way to determine these related tags? I include tag_count because ideally I want to ORDER BY times DESC, so as to find the most relevant, related tags.

Thank you very much

Comment: I think the table `tag` should be called `BlogTags` because it is essentially a junction table.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to want are the additional tags on other blogs that share a tag with some given blog.

So, this suggests some joins and exclusion:

```
select t.tag, count(*)
from (select t2.blog_id as other_blog_id
      from tags t join
           tags t2
           on t.tag = t2.tag and
            t.blog_id <> t2.blog_id 
      where t.blog_id = 2
     ) o join
     tags t
     on o.other_blog_id = t.blog_id
where not exists (select 1
                  from tags tt
                  where tt.blog_id = 2 and tt.tag_id = t.tag_id
                 )
group by t.tag;
```

The first subquery gets the related blog ids.  The outer query then joins this back to the tags and the `not exists` excludes the ones already in blog 2.